# What word would you describe a talk done in a fast fashion?

Tags: word-choice

I live in the U.S. and have encountered many Americans who have the habit of speaking fast as if they are rushed. I want to say to my friend who has this habit

> I find it difficult to keep track of and follow your _______
>   speech.

Now using "fast, quick, rapid" before speech sounds wrong. Is there a word for this?

Comment: ..to follow your **[rapid-fire English](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rapid-fire)** (or rapid-fire speech). And "rapid speech" seems okay..

Comment: You could tell them (him or her): "Could you talk more slowly? I can't keep up with you."

Comment: Fast paced works well, I also like rapid there.

Comment: "jabbering" could work.... as long as your friend isn't easily offended :)

Comment: To this native speaker, "rapid speech" sounds perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with saying, "You're speaking too fast for me. Could you slow down, please?"

That said, if you really wanted a "special" word to fit your exact sentence, you could use the word "auctioneer" as a modifier:

> *I find it difficult to keep track of and follow your ***auctioneer*** speech*.

Auctioneers are famous for speaking unusually fast (one [NPR story](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=17808018) began, "It's the familiar, but sometimes unintelligible voice standing out among all the rest: that fast-talking, number-crunching [auctioneer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8V9Rl9IneA)"), and sometimes this analogy is used to describe people who talk rapidly outside of the auction hall as well. For example, a 2006 *Boston Globe* article about a political candidate began:

> **[Sometimes he talks like an auctioneer](http://www.boston.com/news/local/articles/2006/09/17/on_a_soccer_saturday_gabrieli_keeps_his_eye_fixed_on_the_goal/)**, trying to cram just a few more arguments and anecdotes and ideas into each utterance.

A blogger talked about her hurried, impatient nature by confessing:

> I am the sort of person that impatiently watches the toaster, walks like I am running and [**talks like an auctioneer**](http://kitchenlivingwithcoryanne.com/how-to-caramelized-onions/).   Doing anything slowly is against everything in my nature...

A reporter describes the astronomer he interviewed by saying:

> He talks rapidly, of course. You know that. *The Sky at Night* only runs for 25 minutes. He has to maximise word content. So he [**talks like an auctioneer**](http://www.zone-sf.com/patrickmoore.html) at 300-words-a-minute, snapping the end off words the better to cram them all in.

You could use this word in your sentence if you didn't mind being a little humorous in your request.

Comment: Auctioneer was exactly the word I was thinking  of, too. I'm not sure there's a specific word for them, but the announcers who read the disclaimers at the end of some advertisements also spew out rapid-fire words.

Comment: @RonJ - You and I aren't the only ones; I found this quote on an online discussion forum: _Some radio advertisements, at the conclusion of their pitch, add a 'legal disclaimer' at the end. Typically it's someone that is speaking at hyper-speed like an auctioneer..._